# Adding Spring Security causes columns and tables to be missing

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-security

I've been developing a webapp with Spring Boot. Yesterday I added Spring Security and forced HTTPS for any request, extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and adding

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
```

to the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` overridden method.
I also added an additional `Connector` in a bean returning `ServletWebServerFactory`, which redirects HTTP to HTTPS:

```
Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
connector.setPort(80);
connector.setRedirectPort(443);
```

Suddenly, I get a lot of these errors:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column AAA does not exist
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "BBB" does not exist
```

Where `AAA` and `BBB` are existing in the database (I verified with DataGrip). None of the other code has been touched. I use a `JdbcTemplate` to make queries (no Hibernate/JPA).

I have two years of experience with Spring, and I find this dazzling. Have to say this is my first application done in Spring from scratch, though.

Comment: If you regress those exact changes does the code work again?

Comment: Seems entirely unrelated. The litmus test would be to remove Spring security again and check whether the errors no longer appear.

Comment: Make sure that you've commited the changes to DB scheme. In your DataGrip session AAA & BBB might exist, but not for other sessions.

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko the DB schema was stable since a long time

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this wicked problem. It was that I was passing a wrong connection string via a command line parameter when launching the app with Spring Security enabled.

I regressed the code again after reading your comments and noticed that the same exceptions were thrown, so that immediately excluded Spring Security from the culprits.

I didn't notice it before because my previous launches were done (without noticing) with the correct connection string.

It was a blunder due to a wrong copy-paste from a text file in which I store the command line parameters.

Thanks to you, who confirmed Spring Security and database problems were unrelated, I was able to better direct my search.